# Why Can't I see my SSH Keys in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I used to be able to open Terminal and type `cd ~/.ssh` then `ls -la` to see my keys. After upgrading to Catalina all I see is this

```
./
../
known_hosts
```

Is there a security measure in Catalina that is preventing me from seeing my keys? Or did I lose them? I also haven't upgraded to zsh yet, is that the problem?

Comment: I don't see this issue (I also haven't upgraded to zsh, and recently upgraded to Catalina, and have a ~/.ssh directory). I suspect the directory was moved or deleted. I suggest checking your backups.

Comment: @RobNapier I have a backup of Mojave, and one of Catalina (Both from Carbon Copy Cloner) and do not see anything in the ssh directory on any backups, and another iMac with Catalina, and don't see anything on that iMac either. Really strange.